# Oh My ZSH plugins do not load on startup

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Using iTerm2 or Terminal.app I have to run `su $USER` in order for my plugins to load or display in my prompt (e.g. the RVM plugin).

Any reason why this would be?

Comment: Are you sure your shell is launching zsh and not bash when you startup a terminal?  What happens if you just type `zsh` after you load a shell?

Comment: Can you be more specific, please, and tell us how your zshrc looks like, and if `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` is even called or not? Does it work if you manually execute that command?

Comment: @AndrewM. I am absolutely sure zsh is my login shell. I've run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.


@slhck `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` is called in my .zshrc file.

Thanks for your help guys.

It loads the theme I've selected and my aliases so I'm fairly certain my .zshrc file is being used.

Comment: So ZSH and Oh-my-zsh work, but just all your plugins aren't loaded?

Comment: Correct. (10 chars)

Comment: Ah, good to know.  In interpreted it as "Oh My ZSH the doesn't load." :)  With that being said; so you have any variables or things being set AFTER your `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` is called?  Also, if you run `zsh` after you login, are the plug-ins loaded correctly?  Attaching your `.zshrc` would be a big help as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just a had a similar problem where some plugins appeared to not get executed.  In my case the plugin depended on something installed by homebrew and was failing silently.  So I just made sure `/usr/local/bin` was in $PATH **before** `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`